# How to efficiently find the minimum and maximum of discrete points in a given 2d range

Tags: algorithm

There are 10^6 discrete points (x, y are integers) with values sparsely distributed in a large area [-2^31,2^31)^2. They keep unchanged. Then there are about 10^5 queries, each gives a 2d range (x1, y1) to (x2, y2), asking for the minimum and maximum value in the rectangle (if there are no points there, output -1). What data structure and algorithm should I use to store the input and give the results efficiently?
This is a C++ algorithm problem, and I want it finished in less than 1s.

Comment: How are you defining the "minimum" and the "maximum"? Do you mean in terms of distance from the origin?

Comment: The points have values. They are the minimum and maximum value of the points in the given range.

Comment: @worstcoder it is not clear what you mean by minimum and maximum. For 2D minimum and maximum can be calculated in different ways. If we have (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1) (2, 3), (-1, 10), (-1, 0), (-2, 10), (3, 10), (4, 0), (2, 11) what is min and max for (-100, -100) and (100, 100) rectangular?

Comment: You are asking find two points such that distance between any points lies in rectangle and the output point is minimum or maximum? Do these two points has to be in the rectangle (output -1 if no points are in that rectangle) ?

Comment: Have a look at R-Trees https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

Comment: No, no I mean each point has a "value" (in the actual problem is the temperature of the site) ,which is in the input along with the x,y of the point. The value is an integer given by the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use segment tree 2d for storing and retrieving the results. It is a basic problem for. You should use pointers for reduce memory.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-dimensional-segment-tree-sub-matrix-sum/

Comment: you can also translate this link to english, it is well writen in Russian http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree

Comment: The critical problem is, the range of x,y is too much large than the actual number of points. The points are distributed sparsely, and the storage of the points is possible. But it's impossible to store all the 2^128 points on the plane. There is memory limitation.

Comment: @worstcoder but theres only N points, so if you use pointers actual memory usage will be something like `N*logN*logN`

Answer (score 0):

2D segment tree uses N*N*16 memory, perhaps you are referring to compressed 2D Sparse Table?@Photon